# For any real t and sequence $|x_n|\rightarrow0$, can always find $k_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $k_n |x_n| \to t$?

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the claim* that given a sequence of positive numbers that converges to zero, it is always possible to find a sequence of integers, so that the product sequence converges to any desired real number. I.e. given $\{ x_n \}$, $x_n>0$, $x_n \to 0$, and $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists$ $\{ k_n \}$, $k_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $k_n x_n\to t$.

I am having a bit of difficulty showing this, any tips? Thanks!

*Appears in lemma 3.43 of Brian C. Hall - Lie Group, Lie Algebras, and Representations.

Comment: Thanks! no way I would have found that under that title..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tip:** Take $k_n=\left\lfloor\frac t{x_n}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks! that was embarassingly simple..

Comment: That's why I only provided a tip. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I did not realize this would be useful if a question is marked as duplicate, but done now!